# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at <rich:fileUpload>

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

im trying to upload a file with  like this:

```
        <h:form>
            <rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{bean.test}"
                id="upload" acceptedTypes="jpeg, jpg, gif, png, bmp">
                <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" render="preview" />
            </rich:fileUpload>

        </h:form>
```

But I always get the Error:

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/project] threw exception
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getExceptionHandler(FacesContext.java:280)
at javax.faces.context.FacesContextWrapper.getExceptionHandler(FacesContextWrapper.java:354)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119) 
at ......
```

I used the  before, and it worked fine. I just cant see my mistake.

The Upload Box of it shows, I can add a file. The error appears when i push "upload" and the listener-method (public void test(FileUploadEvent event){..}) is not called.

any idea how i can solve this?

Comment: Are yo using RichFaces 4.1 with MyFaces Orchestra? See also https://community.jboss.org/message/633078

Comment: Im using RichFaces 4.1 with TomCat v7.0. But that cant be the problem, because im using the same versions for the other project(small, not so many libraries) too, where fileUpload works.

Comment: So, you're not using MyFaces Orchestra at all?

Comment: oh sorry. im using MyFaces Orchestra 1.4.

Comment: Okay, there is the cause of the problem. See thus the aforelinked JBoss forum link.

Comment: So the problem is still unsolved and i better take some alternative?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it somehow?

Comment: I can only confirm that this is still an issue with Richfaces 4.3.4

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it turned out that in my packaged `war` file apart from **`myfaces-orchestra-core20`** I also got **`myfaces-orchestra-core12`** which slipped in from another dependency.

Having only that declared in my `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.orchestra</groupId>
      <artifactId>myfaces-orchestra-core20</artifactId>
      <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

and Richfaces verison `4.3.7.Final` made it finally work.